# Authorize.net TransactionResponse error in iOS

Tags: ios, transactions, authorize.net

I have created the **testing** transaction request using **purchaseWithRequest**, always i am getting error

> Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system

My Code:

```
- (void) createTransaction {
    AuthNet *an = [AuthNet getInstance];

    [an setDelegate:self];
    CreditCardType *creditCardType = [CreditCardType creditCardType];
    creditCardType.cardNumber = @"4007000000027";
    creditCardType.cardCode = @"100";
    creditCardType.expirationDate = @"0215";

    PaymentType *paymentType = [PaymentType paymentType];
    paymentType.creditCard = creditCardType;

    ExtendedAmountType *extendedAmountTypeTax = [ExtendedAmountType extendedAmountType];
    extendedAmountTypeTax.amount = @"0";
    extendedAmountTypeTax.name = @"Tax";

    ExtendedAmountType *extendedAmountTypeShipping = [ExtendedAmountType extendedAmountType];
    extendedAmountTypeShipping.amount = @"0";
    extendedAmountTypeShipping.name = @"Shipping";

    LineItemType *lineItem = [LineItemType lineItem];
    lineItem.itemName = @"Soda";
    lineItem.itemDescription = @"Soda";
    lineItem.itemQuantity = @"1";
    lineItem.itemPrice = @"1.00";
    lineItem.itemID = @"1";

    TransactionRequestType *requestType = [TransactionRequestType transactionRequest];
    requestType.lineItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:lineItem];
    requestType.amount = @"1.00";
    requestType.payment = paymentType;
    requestType.tax = extendedAmountTypeTax;
    requestType.shipping = extendedAmountTypeShipping;

    CreateTransactionRequest *request = [CreateTransactionRequest createTransactionRequest];
    request.transactionRequest = requestType;
    request.transactionType = AUTH_ONLY;
    request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.mobileDeviceId =
    [[Utility getDeviceID]
     stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"-" withString:@"_"];
    request.anetApiRequest.merchantAuthentication.sessionToken = sessionToken;
    [an purchaseWithRequest:request];
}
```

Which give call back to this delegate method,

**- (void) requestFailed:(AuthNetResponse *)response {
    // Handle a failed request
    // getting callback to this method
}**

```
- (void) connectionFailed:(AuthNetResponse *)response {
    // Handle a failed connection
}

- (void) paymentSucceeded:(CreateTransactionResponse *) response {
    // Handle payment success
}
```

**Note:** my mobileDeviceRegistrationSucceeded and mobileDeviceLoginSucceeded, only purchaseWithRequestFailed

```
TransactionResponse.errors = (
    "Error.errorCode = 87\nError.errorText = Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system.\n"
)
```

Comment: Getting Following error using above code.

Message.code = E00027
Message.text = The transaction was unsuccessful.

Any solution for that ?

Answer (score 0):

A Market Type Error (Error 87)

**Error Text:** (87) Transactions of this market type cannot be processed on this system.

**What It Means**

This error indicates that the account that you are using was created for Card Present (retail) transactions, but you are trying to integrate to our Card Not Present (e-commerce) APIs or vice versa. The only way to resolve this is to open a new test account with the correct market type. If the error is occurring with a live account, the merchant will need to call Customer Support to see how to get the correct account.
In the coming months, Authorize.Net will be supporting blended accounts that support both Card Present and Card Not Present transactions, which will eliminate this error. When these accounts are available, we’ll post an announcement in the News and Announcements board.